# How to set default value in file upload in JSP

Tags: html, jsp

```
<input type="file" id="formFile" value="c:/passwords.txt">

private FormFile fdlTemplateFile;

public FormFile getFdlTemplateFile() {
   return fdlTemplateFile;
}

public void setFdlTemplateFile(FormFile fdlTemplateFile) {
   this.fdlTemplateFile = fdlTemplateFile;
}
```

i have mention the above id(formFile) in struts also

am trying to show up a file when deploying the page by default i tried this code.... but not working even dont get any error...Thanks in advance for ur help

Answer (score 0):

You cant set default value into input type file. :(